# How can I use generics with exclusive bound using "extends"?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Suppose I have below code snippet with JDK 1.7. Using Generics, I am getting confused how to achieve a generic parameterized type with **exclusive**, **not inclusive** bounds with using `extends`. For example:

```
abstract class BaseAbstract {

}

class ChildWhichExtendsBaseAbstract extends BaseAbstract {

}

class SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics<T extends BaseAbstract> {

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * I just don't want JVM to compile below line, because I want to use
         * generic type with {@link SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics} which must
         * not be {@link BaseAbstract}
         */
        SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics<BaseAbstract> obj1 = 
                new SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics<BaseAbstract>();

        /**
         * I just want JVM to compile below line, because I want to use generic
         * type with {@link SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics} which must be only
         * subclasses of BaseAbstract
         */
        SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics<ChildWhichExtendsBaseAbstract> obj2 = 
                new SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics<ChildWhichExtendsBaseAbstract>();
    }
}
```

I think this should be one of the known problems/issues/requirements. Is there a work around possible?

Comment: When we use bounded type parameter name followed by `extends` we specify a upper bound. In your case it will allow base class and all its derived classes. I do not think you can restrict it to only derived classes.

Comment: A workaround is probably some sort of a runtime check of the elements' type when you add them, but that doesn't help you at compile time.

Comment: that I know, but what if I want to achieve this? no way? any work-arounds?

Answer (score 4):

#### `extends` means an **inclusive upper bound.**

That's it, end of discussion. There isn't really a way to say `extends T` but not `T`. From the [JLS §4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1):

> A type argument T1 is said to contain another type argument T2, written T2 <= T1, if the set of types denoted by T2 is provably a subset of the set of types denoted by T1 under the reflexive and transitive closure of the following rules (where <: denotes subtyping ([§4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10))):
>
> // Snip
>
> - T <= ? extends T

That's it. `T` is contained within `? extends T`.

Additionally, even if you could bound it in this way, it wouldn't really do much. Let's say you could; this would be illegal:

```
public List<? exclusive-extends MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyClass());
```

But this anonymous class wouldn't be:

```
public List<? exclusive-extends MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyClass(){});
```

---

#### There may be a workaround to your real problem, however.

It sounds to me like the real issue is that you don't want anybody to be putting instances of `BaseAbstract` into your generic type; you only want subclasses.

Well, doing **that** is easy enough to achieve; `BaseAbstract` can't be instantiated at all, ever, because it's an abstract class. So as long as the parameterized type is an abstract class, you're ok.

If you have a real class here, and not an abstract class, you can simply put a dummy abstract class in between, e.g.

```
class Foo { }
abstract class AbstractFoo extends Foo { } // Newly added
class Bar extends AbstractFoo { } // previously extended Foo
class Baz extends AbstractFoo { } // previously extended Foo
```

Comment: right, I will try to ask with my actual example later on :) However thanks a lot for you time :)

Answer (score 2):

I see the only option: make `BaseAbstract` package-private and put all the children in the same package. This way `BaseAbstract` will not be accessible from outside. For example, consider the following code.

```
// a/BaseAbstract.java
package a;

abstract class BaseAbstract {

}

// a/ChildWhichExtendsBaseAbstract.java
package a;

public class ChildWhichExtendsBaseAbstract extends BaseAbstract {

}

// a/SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics.java
package a;

public class SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics<T extends BaseAbstract> {

}

// b/Test.java
package b;

import a.ChildWhichExtendsBaseAbstract;
import a.SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * Compile error as BaseAbstract is invisible
         */
        SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics<BaseAbstract> obj1 = 
                new SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics<BaseAbstract>();

        /**
         * Compiles correctly
         */
        SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics<ChildWhichExtendsBaseAbstract> obj2 = 
                new SomeOtherClassWhichUseGenerics<ChildWhichExtendsBaseAbstract>();
    }
}
```

The limitation of this approach is that you should define all the possible child classes in the same package `a`.